# How to Unmarshall CSV file to java object

Tags: java, csv, jaxb, unmarshalling

I know unmarshalling from XML to java class but not sure how to perform unmarshalling for the following file, please help me out.

**FileName : file.txt**

```
1690;0001;DESCRIPTION HERE-1000TW-BK
```

See below the java class,

```
public class TestBean {

String siteId;
String uniqueId;
String description;

//getter-setter below
}
```

tried to unmarshall but getting exception,

```
try{
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestBean.class);
    Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();

    File f = new File("C:\\file.txt");
    TestBean test = (TestBean) u.unmarshal(f);

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Try Apache Camel. It contains processing of CSV and also supports some marshalling/unmarshalling http://camel.apache.org/csv.html

Answer (score 5):

JAXB is used for marshalling/ unmarshalling XML data from/to Java objects.

Your file.txt doesn't contain XML data.

If you have a custom format you will probably have to write your own parser or find an existing one.

Comment: just corrected, it's a `csv` file which i have to transform to java object.

Comment: Thanks Puce. yes, Jaxb can only transform from xml to java.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a `List<TestBean>`.
2. Read the file line by line.
3. For each line;
   a. Split the line on `";"` to get a `String[]`.
   b. Create an instance of `TestBean`.
   c. Add the instance to the list.